# ExpressJS, & AWS DocumentDB connection Authentication Failed

Tags: express, mongoose, amazon-ec2, bitnami, aws-documentdb

I am using ExpressJS to build a Backend Server using AWS EC2 Instance with Bitnami MEAN stack as a server and DocumentDB as the database.

I have tried running the backend codes on my local machine and MongoAtlas and it works perfectly. However, when I tried to connect to the documentDB server by following online guides and tutorials, I meet authentication failures.

The following is my attempt at App.js documentdb connection using Mongoose.

DB_CONNECTION is the connection string that I have copied off the AWS DocumentDB Cluster with my Password included.
(I placed in a separate file and imported it over)

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jocBe.png)

The following is the error that I receive when running node app.js to start the expressJS codes

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZjOX.png)

I've covered certain area in white for privacy, hope you understand.

Online tutorials havent been successful. Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

*I cant embbed images due to by low reputation score. Thank you!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication errors are typically the result of an incorrect username and password. If you are trying to login with master-user and have forgot the password, you can reset the password by modifying the cluster: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/db-cluster-modify.html. If you are trying to login as a regular user, you can reset the password using the mongo shell by using the following command: db.changeUserPassword(username, password)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Checking it as the correct answer as it led me in the correct direction to compare my connection string and check my credentials

Answer (score 2):

Found the error after a long time of debugging. In the connection string, I did not specify the database to connect to. (See example below)

eg. mongodb+srv://:@cluster0.n02wk.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority etc....

This resulted in the connection channeling automatically to the admin database. Due to my account's access permission, my account did not have the permission to access that database, resulting in the Authentication failure.

Added the database name which I intended to connect to and the connection worked!